# Manipulating run time generated div with array name ID

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This successfully generate divs with and array name address as the id for example:

```
<div id="div1[0]" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);"></div>
```

How then does on get a handle on that id using `getElementById()`  examples below do not work.  Either by directly access in the div if through the parent which is used in the constructor which is the array `divArray();`

```js
 var divArray = new Array();   // div array "holder"
 var dCount = 0;      // div array counter

 class dyDiv {

  constructor (){ 

   var parentDiv = document.getElementById('canvas');
   var div1 = document.createElement('div');
   var div2 = document.createElement('div');

   div1.setAttribute("id", "div1["+dCount+"]"); // id="div1[0]"  id="div1[2]" ... and so on
   div2.setAttribute("id", "div2["+dCount+"]");

   div1.style.border = "1px #f00 solid"; // red border
   div2.style.border = "1px #0f0 solid"; // green border

   parentDiv.appendChild(div1);
   parentDiv.appendChild(div2);
  }

 }

 function addNewDiv(){

  divArray[dCount] = new dyDiv();
  dCount++;

 }

 function modifyTest(){
  // after creation how does one manipulate a div inside an object
  divArray[0].div1[0].style.border = "1px #00f solid";      // does not work
  document.getElementById('div10').style.border = "1px #00f solid";   // does not work 
  document.getElementById('div1')[0].style.border = "1px #00f solid";   // does not work
  document.getElementById(div1[0]).style.border = "1px #00f solid";   // does not work
 }

 function init(){
  addNew.addEventListener("click", addNewDiv,false);
  modTest.addEventListener("click", modifyTest,false);
 }


 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init,false);
```

```html
<button id="addNew">Create Dynamic Div</button>
<button id="modTest">Modify divArray[0]</button>
<div style="padding:50px" id="canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the div like this:

```
document.getElementById('div1[0]')
```

Make sure you include the quotes.

Comment: This is in fact the exact solution I was looking for all such associations work.

  document.getElementById('div1[0]').style.border = "1px #00f solid";   
  document.getElementById('div1[0]').innerHTML = "changed";

Comment: @MichaelDouglas Fair enough. If you'll reference each `<div>` with `getElementById`, I don't see much use in building the `divArray`.

Comment: Remember to cache the value of `document.getElementById` to speed up your code. Something like this: `var el = document.getElementById('div1[0]'); el.style.border = "1px #00f solid"; el.innerHTML = "changed";`

Comment: @showdev you are correct I thought it could be beneficial to organise my divs under parent nodes.  During this process I have concluded as you have that there is no value in doing so if I can access divs named in this fashion directly.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you provided, you could use `this` keyword.

> When a function is used as a constructor (with the new keyword), its `this` is bound to the new object being constructed.

See ['this' as a constructor @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_constructor).
Also see the example at [Classes Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor).

```js
var divArray = new Array(); // div array "holder"
var dCount = 0; // div array counter

class dyDiv {

  constructor() {

    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.div1 = document.createElement('div');
    this.div2 = document.createElement('div');

    this.div1.setAttribute("id", "div1[" + dCount + "]"); // id="div1[0]"  id="div1[2]" ... and so on
    this.div2.setAttribute("id", "div2[" + dCount + "]");

    this.div1.style.border = "1px #f00 solid"; // red border
    this.div2.style.border = "1px #0f0 solid"; // green border

    parentDiv.appendChild(this.div1);
    parentDiv.appendChild(this.div2);
  }

}

function addNewDiv() {

  divArray[dCount] = new dyDiv();
  dCount++;

}

function modifyTest() {
  // after creation how does one manipulate a div inside an object
  divArray[0].div1.style.border = "1px #00f solid";
}

function init() {
  addNew.addEventListener("click", addNewDiv, false);
  modTest.addEventListener("click", modifyTest, false);
}


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<button id="addNew">Create Dynamic Div</button>
<button id="modTest">Modify divArray[0]</button>
<div style="padding:50px" id="canvas"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could return an object from your constructor:

> While the default for a constructor is to return the object referenced by `this`, it can instead return some other object (if the return value isn't an object, then the `this` object is returned).

```js
var divArray = new Array(); // div array "holder"
var dCount = 0; // div array counter

class dyDiv {

  constructor() {

    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');

    div1.setAttribute("id", "div1[" + dCount + "]"); // id="div1[0]"  id="div1[2]" ... and so on
    div2.setAttribute("id", "div2[" + dCount + "]");

    div1.style.border = "1px #f00 solid"; // red border
    div2.style.border = "1px #0f0 solid"; // green border

    parentDiv.appendChild(div1);
    parentDiv.appendChild(div2);

    return {
      'div1': div1,
      'div2': div2
    }

  }

}

function addNewDiv() {

  divArray[dCount] = new dyDiv();
  dCount++;

}

function modifyTest() {
  // after creation how does one manipulate a div inside an object
  divArray[0].div1.style.border = "1px #00f solid";
}

function init() {
  addNew.addEventListener("click", addNewDiv, false);
  modTest.addEventListener("click", modifyTest, false);
}


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<button id="addNew">Create Dynamic Div</button>
<button id="modTest">Modify divArray[0]</button>
<div style="padding:50px" id="canvas"></div>
```